# Saying that a user is in "top 100%" isn't nice

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-leagues

[Colin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/163318/colin?tab=profile) is here for the badges, not reputation. And that's okay. Why rub it in by saying he's not even in top 99% of users?

[image: Colin]

It's like saying "he graduated in top 100% of his class".

I suggest not showing percentages above 50%.

Comment: @yellowantphil They only consider users with 200+ rep.

Comment: Or we could make it worse by making an entire question about them all with a *huge* image of their rep and percentage :P

Comment: Three things: 1) If you don't like being in the top 100%, that's some motivation to try to improve, and motivation is good, not bad, 2) I wonder how much overlap there is between "users that actually check this ranking" and "users that would feel bad about it", 3) What's the actual big picture downside of showing "top 100%" even if it doesn't make one feel warm and fuzzy inside (although, tbh, it doesn't bother me, but for argument's sake let's say it does)?

Comment: @JasonC Well, it is highly unlikely a user would actually *check* this, it is showing "top 100% overall" because the user hasn't been active for a while, otherwise they would've had "top x% this quarter/month/week" instead.

Comment: I guess its better than being in the top 101%

Answer (score 3):

As said in discussion that percentage is bit artificial at times.

How about just labeling the button "ranking" instead of "top % overall"?
What do you need that percentage for?

Not showing percentage above 50% would create another problem. Users would be puzzled where the number has gone and how to get it back? That would lead to odd text in button which would try to explain missing percentage.